# Timezone Manipulation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a project (online game) where users have the ability to use a coded 'airport' to travel to different countries & cities. Once they have travelled, the `cityid` within the database will update for example:

`cityid = 1` (England - London)

`cityid = 2` (USA - LA)

Therefore if a user travels from England to the USA it will store database side `cityid = 2`.

Now,

Whilst this is functional, I wish to incorporate timezone changes into it (if at all possible) I have tried:

```
if ($user->cityid == 3)
{
    $timestamp ='1502448414';  //Timestamp which you need to convert
    $dt = new \DateTime("@$timestamp");
    $destinationTimezone = new \DateTimeZone('Mexico/General'); // To which timezone you need to convert
    $dt->setTimeZone($destinationTimezone); // Set timezone
    echo 'Mexico: '. $dt->format('H:i a'), "\n"; // Echo your changed datetime
}
```

As you can see, I have used Mexico as a demo to try and figure out my approach.

However, this only fetches the timestamped time rather than the realtime. Im aware, I could simply add the timestamp into a database table and then run a cron every second to update the table but this seems rather a long winded route.

Now within app.php the standard setting is UTC which runs as a realtime clock by returning: `date('H:i:s')`.

My question is (after a lot of google searching) is there a way to manipulate this to make `date()` output the new time of (USA) when it has been travelled to?

Apologies that I cannot add anymore coding into this question, I have no real idea of how to approach it other than the one stated above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Carbon`

```
if ($user->cityid == 3) {
    $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::now("Your current location timezone");
    $dt->setTimeZone('Mexico/General');
    echo 'Mexico: '. $dt->format('H:i a'), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Should probably come from server time

Comment: @Option You must provide the timestamp. I updated the answer with your placeholder timestamp. Also added one without using `Carbon` library

Comment: Great revision. Seemed to do the trick! Thanks for the assistance.